# Calculating Average Timespan between two dates in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database table with two columns: `StartDateTime` and `FinishDateTime`. both are nullable datetime columns.

I'm wanting to calculate the `Average` time between both fields per row. ie the average duration of my recorded event.

I'm getting a "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type."

Example EF code with a touch of simplification for the demo.

```
from p in new DbContext()
where p.user_id = 123
&& p.StartDateTime != null
&& p.FinishDateTime != null
select new {p.StartDateTime, p.FinishDateTime})
.Average(p=> (p.FinishDateTime.Value - p.StartDateTime.Value).Ticks)
```

I'd love an example of the above, as SQL makes this a breeze.

Comment: What is the `x` in `Average`?

Comment: `x` appears to be a typo. I literally made up the question code as I went. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depends on your data provider, it may support [`DbFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) and you could do something like this:

```
(from p in new DbContext()
where p.user_id = 123
&& p.StartDateTime != null
&& p.FinishDateTime != null
select new {p.StartDateTime, p.FinishDateTime})
.Average(x=> DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(p.FinishDateTime,p.StartDateTime))
```

if it doesn't, i think you have to go linq to objects after the select:

```
(from p in new DbContext()
where p.user_id = 123
&& p.StartDateTime != null
&& p.FinishDateTime != null
select new {p.StartDateTime, p.FinishDateTime})
.ToArray()
.Average(x=> (p.FinishDateTime -p.StartDateTime).Ticks)
```

Comment: Awesome - will give it a go. Was trying to ensure it was generated SQL server side, to avoid pulling the dataset out with a `.ToArray()` or similar